# Gem to local libray in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

My boss asked me to write a gem to wrap an API (canvas) consumer for our app, I did it and it works, but in the last minute he asked me not to use the gem approach but to create a Model of it... I have a vague idea of creating the model for the endpoints and put the code in the controller, but the gem is highly "modularized" so to speak, modules requiring modules and classes inheriting from other classes... Is there some way to include everything just as it is and use like a locally installed library? What is the best approach? My gem depends on Faraday for net_http adapter

Comment: So you already implemented the more complex but also more generic approach and it worked and now your boss now wants to change everything and start over? Did he tell you why?

Comment: Isn't that what the `lib` folder is for. In theory you can put the gem code in the lib folder and then include it from there. Your Model can then be just a front-end to your lib. This also means your code is now versioned with the app itself. Perhaps your boss is OK with this.

Comment: Hi Casper, I think (this is my opinion) the 'lib' folder may be used for external libraries you write like maybe in other languages or like in the old days 'object' code you link to the app (I know there is no more linking code). The name 'Services' is very well suited for this pupose

Comment: Hi @spickermann , I'm not sure, I guess he wants to keep code 'in house'. I know there is a way to bundle a gem from a local directory/folder, but doing so implies some quirks when deployed to production

Comment: Gems do not need to be public. Most apps I maintained in the past use at least a few private gems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We often use the `Service object` approach for this, a good writeup can be found here https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/06/17/using-service-objects-in-ruby-on-rails.html

Basically you put your code in `app/services` and abstract all config and usage away so you can do:

```
result = AppServices::SubscriptionService.new({
           subscription_params: {
             subscription: @subscription,
             coupon: params[:coupon],
             token: params[:stripeToken]
           } 
         }).call
```

So your code could live in `app/services/canvas/lib` for example.

Comment: This is great advice @Benjamin, the requirement to return an OpenStruct object I think is just for practical reasons, I suppose, or, is it a real restriction?

Comment: It's just a preferences of the author afaik. You could return any ruby object. Openstructs are nice because they allow you to write eloquent code. So in the example you could check `result.success?` instead of `result[:success] == true`

Comment: This solution worked as a 'charm' the article you cite is also very professional as you are.